# Setting a HTML div to visible using query

Tags: jquery, html, hidden, visible

I have the following div in a view:

```
<div id=someMessage> Some message </div>
```

that I would like to remain hidden until a jquery script finds that a condition is true and changes it to visible:

```
//in this specific case there are 12 items
if (items > 10) 
{
 $('#someMessage'). (I don't know what to do here, is it best to use html's disabled attribute?)
}
```

If anyone could help out I would be really appreciative. Thanks

Comment: what are you trying to do actually..? where's your rest of the script..?

Comment: set a div to hidden by default, and when a condition is true, set it to visible using query

Answer (score 2):

Set div hidden by default :

```
<div id=someMessage style="display:none"> Some message </div>
```

And later, show it using the jQuery's show() method :

```
//in this specific case there are 12 items
if (items > 10) 
{
 $('#someMessage').show();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using CSS hide it initially,

```
#someMessage { display:none; }
```

Then by script `toggle` the display of that element by using the condition that you have,

```
$('#someMessage').toggle(items>10);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply `$('#someMessage').show();`

You can also edit the CSS rules of the element like that:

```
$("#someMessage").css("visibility","visible");
```

See this link for more informations: http://api.jquery.com/show/

Answer (score 0):

Create this CSS rule:

```
.invisible {
    display: none;
}
```

If a tag has this class, it is hidden. If a tag does not have this class, it is shown. You can hide items by calling:

```
$(selector).addClass("invisible");
```

You can show items by calling:

```
$(selector).removeClass("invisible");
```

You can check whether an item is invisible:

```
$(selector).hasClass("invisible")
```

I like this solution more than using jQuery's `hide` and `show` functions, because you have an easy way to check whether an item is invisible this way.